# why Pycharm open MutableMapping in typing.py instead of the class MutableMapping definition in _collections_abc.py

Tags: python, pycharm

I am quite new in python. I met a situation that Pycharm goes to typing.py if I click the parameter MutableMapping, which is expected to goes to the MutableMapping class definition in _collection_abc.py.

python 3.7.6

[image]

The Pycharm goes to typing.py instead of _collection_abc.py:
[image]

I don't know why Pycharm lead to typing.py when I try to see the source of "Mapping". Is there anything I miss?

Comment: It appears to either be a bug, or they're passively trying to point you to the class they think you should be using instead (which would be odd). The definition in typing is a wrapper over the `collections.abc`, so it might be getting confused? Although Pycharm is usually quite smart.

Comment: Even if you do `import collections.abc` then `collections.abc.Iterable`, then mouse-over `Iterable`, it will bring up `typing` information.

Comment: I tried in vscode using the same code.It also leads to typing.py. It seems not the pycharm bug

Comment: Both could be relying on the same library to do the lookups.